# Is there a way to set the size of /dev/shm globally so the --shm-size flag doesn't need to be set as part of docker run?

Tags: docker, containers

I would like to be able to have /dev/shm preset to a different value than 64 MB, so that any container I spin up automatically takes on that new value.

I know I can run

```
docker run --shm-size=2G some-container
```

but i'd like to be able to do this without having to add the --shm-size flag. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set default value in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:/etc/docker$ cat daemon.json
{
    "default-shm-size": "1G"
}
```

If do not have this file, you can new a file and add configure to it.

After modify, restart docker service:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Then, confirm it with next command:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:/etc/docker$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu df -h | grep shm
shm             1.0G     0  1.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

You can see shared memory already set as 1G just the value you set in `daemon.json`, detail refers to [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).